# FabricJS - Tips of arrows rendering with artefacts when being dragged

Tags: fabricjs

When drawing lines with arrows onto a FabricJS canvas the tips of the arrows render strangely when being dragged around the canvas. Once the `mouse:up` event fires the arrow stays as it was when dropped with artefacts on the canvas.

[image: Example of artefacts]

Running the code snippet below and then clicking and dragging will draw arrows.

```js
const LineWithArrow = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Line, {
  type: 'line_with_arrow',

  initialize(element, options) {
    options || (options = {});
    this.callSuper('initialize', element, options);

    // Set default options
    this.set({
      hasBorders: false,
      hasControls: false,
    });
  },

  _render(ctx) {
    this.callSuper('_render', ctx);
    ctx.save();
    const xDiff = this.x2 - this.x1;
    const yDiff = this.y2 - this.y1;
    const angle = Math.atan2(yDiff, xDiff);
    ctx.translate((this.x2 - this.x1) / 2, (this.y2 - this.y1) / 2);
    ctx.rotate(angle);
    ctx.beginPath();
    // Move 5px in front of line to start the arrow so it does not have the square line end showing in front (0,0)
    ctx.moveTo(5, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(-5, 5);
    ctx.lineTo(-5, -5);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = this.stroke;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.restore();
  },
});

const drawLineWithArrow = (points) => (
  new LineWithArrow(points, {
    strokeWidth: 2,
    stroke: 'black',
  })
)

const selectLine = (points) => {
  return drawLineWithArrow(points);
}

let line;
let isDown;

const fabricCanvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', {
  height: 500,
  width: 500,
  targetFindTolerance: 15,
  selection: false,
  preserveObjectStacking: true,
  perPixelTargetFind: true, // To prevent the line having a selectable rectangle drawn around it and instead only have it selectable on direct click
});

fabricCanvas.on('mouse:down', (options) => {
  isDown = true;
  const pointer = fabricCanvas.getPointer(options.e);
  const points = [pointer.x, pointer.y, pointer.x, pointer.y];
  line = selectLine(points);
  fabricCanvas
    .add(line)
    .setActiveObject(line)
    .renderAll();
});

fabricCanvas.on('mouse:move', (options) => {
  if (!isDown) return;
  const pointer = fabricCanvas.getPointer(options.e);
  line.set({ x2: pointer.x, y2: pointer.y });
  fabricCanvas.renderAll();
});

fabricCanvas.on('mouse:up', () => {
  isDown = false;
  line.setCoords();
  fabricCanvas.setActiveObject(line).renderAll();
});
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.21/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think is an artifact of cache clearing because you modified the size of ab object, but fabric does not know it.

You arrow head is bigger than the line, but fabricjs has no knowledge about it.

Override this function and add a bit more of space:

```
_getCacheCanvasDimensions: function() {
  var zoom = this.canvas && this.canvas.getZoom() || 1,
      objectScale = this.getObjectScaling(),
      retina = this.canvas && this.canvas._isRetinaScaling() ? fabric.devicePixelRatio : 1,
      dim = this._getNonTransformedDimensions(),
      zoomX = objectScale.scaleX * zoom * retina,
      zoomY = objectScale.scaleY * zoom * retina,
      width = dim.x * zoomX,
      height = dim.y * zoomY;
  return {
    // for sure this ALIASING_LIMIT is slightly crating problem
    // in situation in wich the cache canvas gets an upper limit
    width: width + ALIASING_LIMIT,
    height: height + ALIASING_LIMIT,
    zoomX: zoomX,
    zoomY: zoomY,
    x: dim.x,
    y: dim.y
  };
```

This was just to explain. In your particular case you can consider just disable the objectCaching on mousedown/mousemove, and re-enable it on mouseUp, or keep it disabled adding `objectCaching: false` to your arrow class.

```js
const LineWithArrow = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Line, {
  type: 'line_with_arrow',

  hasBorders: false,
  hasControls: false,

    _getCacheCanvasDimensions() {
      var dim = this.callSuper('_getCacheCanvasDimensions');
      dim.width += 15; // found by trial and error
      dim.height += 15; // found by trial and error
      return dim;
    },
  
  _render(ctx) {
    this.callSuper('_render', ctx);
    ctx.save();
    const xDiff = this.x2 - this.x1;
    const yDiff = this.y2 - this.y1;
    const angle = Math.atan2(yDiff, xDiff);
    ctx.translate((this.x2 - this.x1) / 2, (this.y2 - this.y1) / 2);
    ctx.rotate(angle);
    ctx.beginPath();
    // Move 5px in front of line to start the arrow so it does not have the square line end showing in front (0,0)
    ctx.moveTo(5, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(-5, 5);
    ctx.lineTo(-5, -5);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = this.stroke;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.restore();
  },
});

const drawLineWithArrow = (points) => (
  new LineWithArrow(points, {
    strokeWidth: 2,
    stroke: 'black',
  })
)

const selectLine = (points) => {
  return drawLineWithArrow(points);
}

let line;
let isDown;

const fabricCanvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', {
  height: 500,
  width: 500,
  targetFindTolerance: 15,
  selection: false,
  preserveObjectStacking: true,
  perPixelTargetFind: true, // To prevent the line having a selectable rectangle drawn around it and instead only have it selectable on direct click
});

fabricCanvas.on('mouse:down', (options) => {
  isDown = true;
  const pointer = fabricCanvas.getPointer(options.e);
  const points = [pointer.x, pointer.y, pointer.x, pointer.y];
  line = selectLine(points);
  fabricCanvas
    .add(line)
    .setActiveObject(line)
    .renderAll();
});

fabricCanvas.on('mouse:move', (options) => {
  if (!isDown) return;
  const pointer = fabricCanvas.getPointer(options.e);
  line.set({ x2: pointer.x, y2: pointer.y });
  fabricCanvas.renderAll();
});

fabricCanvas.on('mouse:up', () => {
  isDown = false;
  line.setCoords();
  fabricCanvas.setActiveObject(line).renderAll();
});
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.21/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. `objectCaching: false` solved it.